Why do atoms absorb photons?
im studying spectra/spectroscopy in school in my chemistry class, and im having to resort to re-teaching myself the chapter due to my teacher's abilities (or lack thereof)
i understand how they absorb them to a degree, but im not really finding answers on the WHY, like if electrons want to occupy the lowest possible energy levels because its the most stable situation to be in, why would the atom absorb the photon at all?? why absorb it in the first place?
ive been finding round-a-bout answers, like they do it cause the photons are matching the energy difference between electron energy levels, but thats the what, and i need the WHY!
i really hope someone can clear this up for me, im so confused, thanks so much

Hi Hannah and welcome to the Physics SE. It's a great question but I think it's covered by the existing question I've linked above. Have a look and see if the linked question helps.

In one sense, you can think of a rock that also "wants" to be at the bottom of a hill. Why does it allow you to push it up? You exert a force on the rock and give it energy. Atoms absorb photons because photons give them energy.
In another sense, physics doesn't answer why questions. Physics is a description of the behavior of the universe. It describes how the universe behaves, but not why. All physics can say is that effects follow causes, photons give energy to electrons, and so on.

ah, okay, thank you so much for clearing that up! i really appreciate it. honestly, the distinction between chem and phys helped a lot, i realised i was associating the concept with chemistry when i should've been thinking in physics terms. definitely gonna keep the phrase "physics doesnt answer why questions" in mind going forward.
so to clarify, the atoms and photons don't decide perse, its just something that happens due to the nature/role/properties of the photon?

First of all, electromagnetic waves are relatively well-coupled to electric charges. The coupling strength is given by something called the fine structure constant which has the value of about (1/137). So if you give them the chance, photons will readily interact with electrons.
In an atom, electrons are confined to occupy only certain well-defined energy levels, and they will arrange themselves into that configuration which has the lowest overall energy content. This is why they all want to occupy the lowest level- but the occupancy rules prohibit this, and the remaining electrons have to stack themselves up into progressively higher energy levels.
If the energy difference between two neighboring energy levels is very close to the energy carried by an incoming photon, and if the higher of the two energy levels is not already occupied by an electron, then the photon can give up its energy to the electron which is then boosted into that higher energy level.
To make things interesting, it so happens that in many kinds of atoms, this boost energy corresponds to the energy associated with electromagnetic wavelengths in the range of infrared to visible to ultraviolet light, and bingo! You get spectra which are unique to each different kind of atom.
I have left out a lot of the details here, so this represents just the basics. I invite the experts here to provide more detail.
